# arcgis map idle event

Tags: google-maps, dom-events, arcgis-js-api

Can you please help me on below-

Do we have any "idle" map event using arcgis API for Javascript.?

We do have "idle" map event in Google? In the similar lines, I need for arcgis api.

Sample of Google idle event-

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() { updateMap(); });
```

Or else it will even be helpful if you can please let me know how do we know the map is idle in arcgis API Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

you could easily define what is NOT idle , I mean mouse movement for example.
and on mouse move

```
var isIdle;
function _setnotIdle(){
var isIdle = false;
}
map.on("mouse-move", _setnotIdle);
      map.on("mouse-drag", _setnotIdle);
```

than on some

```
setTimeOut(function _isIdle(){
isIdle = true;
},TIME_OUT_VAL);
```